# Kernel error after updating Spyder in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, kernel, spyder

I updated Spyder to version 4.1.0 (together with all other packages in anaconda). Spyder itself works fine however the kernel is not working. I get the following error and can't figure out how to solve it:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\20172010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1209, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\20172010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 267, in start_kernel
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, env=env, **kw)
File "C:\Users\20172010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 211, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\20172010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\20172010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\20172010\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I have the same problem and had to downgrade to 4.0.1 (which solved the issue). I have also tried to Reset to factory defaults, but it did not help. I am not sure what you mean by starting Spyder graphically, but there should be a general solution.

Comment: @Forinstance its through Anaconda Navigator

Comment: Not a good start to 4.1... 4.0.1 was constantly crashing with no discernible pattern, lets see how this version goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link below is mentioned that they are working to roll out spyder 4.1.1 asap.

In the meantime you have two options:

- run spyder 4.1.0 via the Navigator or prompt (as mentioned earlier)
- perform a rollback to 4.0.1 in the navigator

Link: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11819

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same issue, I started Spyder using Anaconda Navigator instead of calling only Spider (desktop icon) and it worked.

Somehow the logic calling Spyder outside Anaconda Navigator misses something Anaconda Navigator doesn´t.

Answer (score 2):

So somehow if i start Spyder graphically from the anaconda menu it works (which solves the problem).